# Checking CSS within a rails controller or in plain ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parsing

I need to take a database text field and parse it for

1. duplication and garbage
2. malice
3. whitelisted selectors
4. compress and output as a css file

Since there might be a rails way I'm unaware or something ready made I'm asking before I waste time trying to reinvent a wheel. My searching revealed nothing, mostly in rails seems aimed at view level, and css seems to be an unattended niche in this area (plenty of html though).

I'm aware of the sanitize gem (doesn't do css immediately, yet another thing I'd need to map out and code) and the built in rails stuff (not a lot of tutorial, aimed mostly at the view level). I need a gem, lib, module or something similar that I can work with in a controller or queue.

EDIT:

Without getting too deep into the specifics of the project: administrative users can add css for their portions of the site. As part of the flow I'm going to save the raw css and then process and save the processed css. The db stuff is archival mostly, the css file is output immediately. Because there is few places to add modified css and only admins have access to the css, it sort of works but I'm looking to make it more robust in the future where admins who may not be as conversant with the security needs or not as css aware can operate.

The most basic example is that it just a text field on an admin page. The admin cuts and pastes css there, submits, and the application turns it into a css file that gets included with the designated pages, which works because the current admins know the application, the css of the application, and what they can and cannot change. The goal is to make this more robust for future admins who might not be as savvy.

Comment: you're building a stylesheet from values in a database, correct?  yes this is unusual.  I was thinking mistype csv but no looks like you really want css.  Could you explain the usage a little more, e.g. "My company want to store it's stylesheet information in a database so that it can more easily be shared and we can write an application against it to modify and maintain the styles centrally" - or whatever your needs are.  Might help people thinking about the answer and it might encourage lateral thinking.

Comment: Intriguing. What are you storing in the database that you need to convert to a CSS file? An example of the database input and the CSS output would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply sanitize CSS, you can use the SanitizeHelper built into Rails: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize_css

---

Have you looked at Sass? It has all of the parsing logic built in, for a superset of CSS. You could add a feature (Sass support) and save yourself the need to parse/validate the CSS all in one go.

You can generate output CSS from Sass (or just plain CSS, since Sass [with the SCSS syntax] is a fully-backward-compatible superset of CSS) like this:

```
output_css = Sass::Engine.new(sass_content, :syntax => :scss).render
```

There are a bunch of options that you'll probably want to look into at http://sass-lang.com/

---

Another option is Less. The new Twitter Bootstrap framework uses Less, and Rails 3.1 uses Sass. The biggest difference is that the official Less parser/compiler is built in JavaScript, so you could actually validate and compile in the user's browser while they work and show them any errors *before* they save. Of course then you need to run a JavaScript engine (e.g. V8) in your Rails application if you want to use Less to validate the incoming CSS still.

Comment: Interesting, I'm using sass in development, but I'm not aware of the more evolved aspects. Examples in existing projects? I'll look further.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the more evolved aspects". On one of my projects, I'm using Sass like this to combine color themes with layout templates on a pick-and-choose basis to generate semi-custom websites. I can't really offer up the code, but I just added a route with a `css` format that goes to a assemble.css.erb file and renders just like you see above.

Comment: More evolved from my perspective meaning advanced usage, to be more precise. I can handle the basics of sass, but I'm not an advanced developer (I've just been cobbling things together as I've needed for a while). I do remember reading something about theming, but didn't follow up. But I've tried your suggestion and it should be useful in the long run for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I still do not have reference to whitelisting and a malice check(and I'm not sure I need them immediately as I can only accept valid css at this point), but this tidies up a lot for my project in the interim.

Comment: Just updated the question to include a link to this as well in case someone misses it, but here it is: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize_css